# laravel morphable get the source

Tags: php, laravel

I have morphable table named `documents` this table stores files from other tables such as `users` `products` etc.

So far everything is working fine but I also need to get documents source information in admin panel.

**Example**

```
doc 1  => product ABC
doc 2 => user XYZ
```

I need to get this `product ABC` and `user XYZ` as source of each document. **How can I do that?**

**Code**

`controller`

```
public function index()
{
  $documents = Document::orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
  return view('admin.documents.index', compact('documents'));
}
```

`blade`

```
@foreach($documents as $document)
  {{$document->name}}
  // here need source name
@endforeach
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

Models relationship

`product model`

```
public function documents()
{
  return $this->morphMany(Document::class, 'documentable');
}
```

`Document model`

```
protected $fillable = [
  'documentable_id', 'documentable_type', 'file', 'download_count',
];

public function documentable()
{
  return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Document model relationships?

Comment: @designtocode I'm so sorry bro got lost in tons of works :) here i updated my question for you.

Comment: Try `$document->documentable`. To check if it's a product or user, check the value of `$document->documentable_type`

Comment: ok i will try and let you know